# Are https://sub.example.com and https://example.com considered Cross-Domain?

Tags: dns, cross-domain, subdomain, google-ads-api

I'm tracking google ads, my user will first go to

1. User goes to: https://example.com
2. And then click a link
3. User will go through multiple redirects
4. Finally redirect to https://sub.example.com

My question is, are https://sub.example.com and https://example.com considered Cross-Domain?

If they are Cross-Domain, should I enable [google ads Cross-Domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/linker?hl=en)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are considered different domains, but you do NOT need to use cross domain tracking. You just need to add one to the referral exclusion list. Here's a great article on how to do just that: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/subdomain-tracking-with-google-analytics-and-google-tag-manager/